# JS, Rails, CSS - align buttons to bottom of something else on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three buttons in separate columns. The columns contain dynamic content which could move any number of the buttons around.

How can I align all three buttons regardless of the dynamic content's height?

http://www.bootply.com/GWxs97wM3q

Also, maybe the I should change the layout I have to have a col-md-12 or row at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Maybe the best thing to do is use row or additional div for buttons with width 100%

Comment: @NickCatib that's what I ended up doing. I wish there were another way too. Make an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we agreed in the comment section,  maybe the best thing to do is use row or additional div for buttons with width 100%...